# Validating Django SelectDateWidget

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

My problem is that I am using a DateField in Django Form and in that Date Field I am using SelectDateWidget. Now I have a single Date field in my form but while rendering SelectDateWidget convert it into 3 Select Fields, now while Posting and check the form using is_valid I am not able to validate the form bcos the form contains only one Date field but I am getting 3 post variables in request.POST.

So my question is how do i validate the form with SelectDateWidget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late, but I hope it helps. I struggled with this for a while. This is a symptom of not using `USE_L10N`. If you check out the source for [Select Date Widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#SelectDateWidget), you will see that `value_from_datadict` returns a date in the following format: `'%s-%s-%s' % (y, m, d)` with non-zero padded numbers. So there are a few things you can do there:

### Use internationalisation

You can do this by setting in your settings:

```
USE_L10N = True
```

This will cause `value_from_datadict` to attempt to return the date in your first specified format.

### Make your date field accept returned date format

Make your date field accept dates in the format that is returned. This appears to be `%Y-%-m%-d` based on the source code for Django 1.11. So your date field might look like:

```
date_field = models.DateField(
    input_formats=['%Y-%-m%-d']
)
```

### Subclass `SelectDateWidget` and override the return value

You can override the return value of `SelectDateWidget.value_from_datadict` to match the date format that you are expecting to receive. For example, if your expected date format was `%d/%m/%Y`, then you might override with the following:

```
class CustomSelectDateWidget(SelectDateWidget):
"""
Overwrites `SelectDateWidget` to provide the expected date format.
"""

def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
    y = data.get(self.year_field % name)
    m = data.get(self.month_field % name)
    d = data.get(self.day_field % name)
    if y == m == d == "0":
        return None
    if y and m and d:
        if settings.USE_L10N:
            input_format = get_format('DATE_INPUT_FORMATS')[0]
            try:
                date_value = datetime.date(int(y), int(m), int(d))
            except ValueError:
                return '%02d/%02d/%02d' % (int(d), int(m), int(y))
            else:
                date_value = datetime_safe.new_date(date_value)
                return date_value.strftime(input_format)
        else:
            return '%02d/%02d/%02d' % (int(d), int(m), int(y))
    return data.get(name)
```